# How i can send a real time email when capture a lead from Facebook

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, facebook

Wondering if there is any way to send an email "through journey builder" whenever capture a lead from Facebook. any way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is unfortunately no method for sending a real time email upon submission of a lead capture form from Facebook. At least using the standard Lead Ads solution in Advertising Studio. You can build a solution utilising Automation Studio, but you will be limited to the frequency of scheduled automation executions.

What is worth clarifying is which Contact/Subscriber Key you are using in your setup. The data extensions holding leads from Facebook Lead Ads only hold the email address, and given you use a different ID (which I hope you do), this should first be resolved, prior to sending an email or injecting this new lead to a journey.

There are few options for reducing the latency, but they either come with a cost (a.o. Zapier provides a real time integration platform for Lead Ads to Sales Cloud, which of course only works in a cross cloud environment) or comes with some development effort. The latter will utilise [Facebook Lead Ads API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/), calling a Webhook in your end. This Webhook could be hosted as a [Code Resource](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cp_code_resource.htm&type=5), and orchestrate following process:

1. Lookup if the lead is already known (e.g. you don't want to send welcome email if person is already subscribing to your emails
2. If no existing Contacts are found, a new Contact ID is created
3. Contact gets injected into journey, using API entry event

The development of such an integration goes beyond the scope of this forum, as the vast majority of the solutioning and development goes into creating the Facebook app to capture the leads and push them to the webhook.

Comment: Thanks, @Lukas I am proceeding with the delay of 1 hour. Data will come to a DE and every hour journey will run and will send email to only new users.

Answer (score -1):

This depends on how your leads from Facebook are imported to Salesforce.
For different lead sources - I have different forms with different hidden fields.
My FB form has the hidden field Lead Source = Facebook and another hidden field indicating that they are a new lead.
If both of these fields are selected - I have Marketing Cloud set to send emails until they are no longer a new lead.